# Signout inactive user next auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, session-cookies, next-auth

I want to signout the inactive user in my app , I set the maxAge of ...nextauth to one minute and the refetch interval to 20s of SessionProvider , but the session expiration on the cookie of browser will be added by the value of maxAge (one minute added every 20s)  .
of I set just maxAge the client is signout but the server and the client is not affected , when I open a tab and return to my app tab the session is reftched and find the session cookie expired so the ui display that the user is not authenticated [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHwNc.png)

when the next-auth-session expired the client on the server is disconnected but on the client still connected on the ui , I want to sync the client and server with the new status of the user

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need a client side component that periodically checks for user activity and invalidates the cookie if inactivity was detected. By being on the client side you can then redirect the user somewhere else.

```
"use client";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useRef, useCallback } from "react";

const MAX_INACTIVITY_MS = 20000;

/*
 * Import component through "next/dynamic" with ssr set to false.
 * Simply include it somewhere inside your root layout.
 */
export default function InactivityGuard(): JSX.Element {
  const router = useRouter();
  const timer = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout>(setTimeout(() => {}, 0));

  // just an example, logout the user when this is called
  const onLogout = useCallback(async () => {
    await fetch("/api/session/logout", { cache: "no-store" });
    router.replace("/logout");
  }, [router]);

  // this function resets the timer on each mouse move or key press
  const onReset = useCallback(() => {
    if (timer.current) clearTimeout(timer.current);
    timer.current = setTimeout(onLogout, MAX_INACTIVITY_MS);
  }, [onLogout]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window === undefined) return;
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", onReset);
    window.addEventListener("keypress", onReset);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", onReset);
      window.removeEventListener("keypress", onReset);
    };
  }, []);

  return <></>;
}
```

Of course this is a very naive way to check for inactivity and could be heavily improved, but it's just a quick example. You may also want to listen for the `click`, `touchstart` and `scroll` events to improve the detection accuracy. Maybe even consider debouncing the function calls to improve the component performance.

Comment: but when I set maxAge is the same as inactive time , when I call a session to get a token the max age time is renew that's means the next-session-auth-token expiration renew with the value of maxAge , when maxAge reached so the server is disconnect but the client still on mode connected , the thing is just to notify client that the session is expired on server to update the ui  ,

Comment: @AbderrahmaneBOUHIR This example I have posted assumes that the token does not have a `maxAge` property and the user is signed out in the `onLogout ` function as you can see by the API call to `/api/session/logout`. The client side invalidates the token and updates the UI.